# Scroll SpriteNode using touches

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

I want to scroll a node in sprite kit without uiscrollview

// **In touchesMoved**

```
let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch;
let location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self);
let lastPosition = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

var newLoc = selectNode.position.y + (location.y - lastPosition.y)
// Check if the top part is reached
if(newLoc < selectNodeStart){
    newLoc = selectNodeStart
}

if(selectNode.position.y >= selectNodeStart){
    // let sk = SKAction.moveToY(newLoc, duration: 0.1)
    // selectNode.runAction(sk)
    selectNode.position.y = newLoc
}
```

If I use the **sk** action the result is very horrible, but without the result is also horrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Elegant way of doing this in SpriteKit is using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to detect the touch, and inside of that you will create a sequence of SKActions that will accelerate or decelerate the movement. You might have to use the `update` method and/or `touches` to handle the pan stopping or another immediately starting. Unfortunately, if you want to use only SpriteKit you will have to use SKActions to implement this.

I thought I'd also mention an easier (and possible better looking) way to do this. Take a look at "ScrollKit", which works pretty well (although it does use a UIScrollView): https://github.com/bobmoff/ScrollKit

If you found that the UIScrollView doesn't pass touches up to `touchesMoved`, you could try a few different things. 
- You can add a UITapGestureRecognizer and set on the UIScrollView `CanCancelContentTouches` to `YES`. 

 - You can subclass UIScrollView and override the touchesMethods so that if the user isn't scrolling, touch information will be passed up the responder chain:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){

     if (!self.dragging){
         self.nextResponder.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent: event) 
     }
     else{
         super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent: event)
     }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){

    if (!self.dragging){
        self.nextResponder.touchesMoved(touches , withEvent:event)  
    }
    else{
        super.touchesMoved(touches , withEvent: event)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent: event UIEvent){

    if (!self.dragging){ 
         self.nextResponder.touchesEnded(touches , withEvent: event)
    }
    else{
        super.touchesEnded(touches , withEvent: event)
    }    
}
```

Comment: I have to be able to tap on the node inside the scroll view, using ScrollKit swift version the code in touchesBegan never runs. Do you have an example with UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: @grape1 take a look at my edit, it should help you with the touchesMethods and ScrollKit. A custom implementation with the UIPanGestureRecognizer would be rather complex if it was to look good (since everything would be done with SKActions and you've already seen how that goes). Personally, I've never had a problem with how it looks but I've never had to create a long scrolling action either. For that, I'd go to something like ScrollKit for simplicity.

Comment: ScrollKit is too much for what I need. A simple vertical scrolling node which contain a grid of characters to select.

Comment: I end up subclassing UIScrollView, thanks for the help